# React - Date input value not updated to state

Tags: reactjs

In my React App, I am able to set the state and update the database for all values except the date input field. My code is below:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    ...
    ...
    import DateInput from '../others/input/datePicker'
    ...
    ..
      change = (what, e) => this.setState({ [what]: e.target.value })

      changeDOB() {
        this.setState({ age: document.getElementByClassNames("datePicker").value })
      }

      render() {
        let {
    ...
    ...
    age,
    ...
      } = this.state
    ...
    ...
    //date of birth
    let stringAge = age.toString()
    stringAge =
      stringAge.substring(0, 4) +
      '-' +
      stringAge.substring(4, 6) +
      '-' +
      stringAge.substring(6, 8)
    ...
                    <DateInput
                      type="date"
                      change={this.changeDOB}
                      placeholder={stringAge}
                      className="datePicker"
                    />

...
...
const mapStateToProps = store => ({
  ud: store.User.user_details,
  tags: store.User.tags,
  session: store.User.session,
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(EditProfile)
export { EditProfile as PureEditProfile }
```

Here is DateInput code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { string, func, oneOf, bool } from 'prop-types'

const DateInput = ({ type, placeholder, ...props }) => (
  <input
    type={type}
    placeholder={placeholder}
    spellCheck="false"
    autoComplete="false"
    {...props}
  />
)

DateInput.defaultProps = {
  type: 'date',
  placeholder: '',
  disabled: false,
}

DateInput.propTypes = {
  type: oneOf(['date']),
  placeholder: string.isRequired,
  maxLength: string,
  disabled: bool,
}

export default DateInput
```

I tried `this.change` like other fields but that does not work either.

How to get the new value updated in the state ?

Note: The text is red is the value currently in the database.

[image]

Comment: Seems you are not binding this.changeDOB in constructor. Add this.changeDOB = this.changeDOB.bind(this); in constructor or use arrow functions. Also You are passing this.changeDOB to change props in DateInput component so is DateInput a librrary or your custom component?

Comment: Please include DateInput component code also

Comment: could you please console `document.getElementByClassNames("datePicker").value` within `changeDOB` function ?

Comment: import DateInput from '../others/input/datePicker' ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `onChange` attribute for the input field in the `DateInput`  component as

```
const DateInput = ({ type, placeholder, ...props }) => (
  <input
    type={type}
    placeholder={placeholder}
    spellCheck="false"
    autoComplete="false"
    onChange = {props.Onchange}
    {...props}
  />
)
```

Then your main component should be as

```
  changeDOB(e) {
       this.setState({ age: e.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return(
              <DateInput
                  type="date"
                  Onchange={this.changeDOB}
                  placeholder={stringAge}
                  className="datePicker"
                />
          )
             }
```

Please find a working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/l7wx0wl379)

Comment: Thank you. I changed the code but the value is still not updating in database. I am  probably doing something wrong. I cannot figure out at all. I will try tomorrow and update the results.

Comment: No, state still is the same value. BUT if I change the input type to a simple text field instead of DateInput, the database gets updated. So I am doing something wrong

Comment: @Harikrishnan -  yes, I had to modify to getElementById - `changeDOB = () => {this.setState({ age: document.getElementById("datePicker").value })}`.. For some reason getElementByClassName was causing the issue. Also had to add `value={age}` to DateInput

Answer (score 0):

You are passing all the props to input component but you need to pass your event handler function to onchange input element or Try onkeypress instead. Something like below. You can also try getting input value with event instead of document

Arrow function: No need of manual binding

```
changeDOB = (event) => {
    this.setState({ age: event.target.value 
      })
  }

<DateInput
    type="date"
    change={this.changeDOB}
    placeholder={stringAge}
    className="datePicker"
    value={this.state.age}
 />

<input
    type={type}
    placeholder={placeholder}
    spellCheck="false"
    autoComplete="false"
    onchange={(event) => props.change(event)}
    value={props.value}
    {...props}
  />
```

Normal function: Binding required and only in constructor

```
this.changeDOB = this.changeDOB.bind(this);

  changeDOB(event){
    this.setState({ age: event.target.value  
      })
  }

<DateInput
    type="date"
    change={this.changeDOB}
    placeholder={stringAge}
    className="datePicker"
    value={this.state.age}
 />


  <input
    type={type}
    placeholder={placeholder}
    spellCheck="false"
    autoComplete="false"
    onchange={props.change}
    value={props.value}
    {...props}
  />
```

Comment: Thanks. As soon as I add `value=` in date input, the date picker does not change the date anymore. When I change the input type to a simple text field instead of DateInput, the database gets updated. So I am doing something wrong. I will try tomorrow and update as its too late. Thanks for the help

Comment: Does not work - State does not update and also date picker does not change date when value is added.

Answer (score 0):

The date is being taken in the ISO format whereas the display expects it in the localformat.
This worked for me:

```html
 const [deadline, setDeadline] = useState(new Date());
 
 
 <input
        type="date"
        id="start"
        name="trip-start"
        value={deadline.toLocaleDateString}
        onChange={(event) => setDeadline({deadline:event.target.value})}
        min="2022-01-01"
        max="2022-12-31"
      >
 </input>
```